# Magento 2 V1/search

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am not able to understand the what the api V1/search does. For example -

```
http://localhost:8080/magento/index.php/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[requestName]=catalog_view_container&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=color&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=49
```

When i hit the api of v1/search then the output is-

```
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": 419,
          "custom_attributes": [
            {
              "attribute_code": "score",
              "value": "0.0000000000000000"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 846,
          "custom_attributes": [
            {
              "attribute_code": "score",
              "value": "0.0000000000000000"
            }
          ]
        },
}
```

I am not able to understand what does this output shows,
what is the meaning of request name here. I want to know that what kind of product data i can get using this v1/searh api.

Answer (score 2):

`rest/V1/search` responsible for Search (Fulltext, layered navigation).

For example:  lets try search all products contains `simple`

`http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[requestName]=quick_search_container&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=search_term&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=simple`

Result will be

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1497,
      "custom_attributes": [
        {
          "attribute_code": "score",
          "value": "170.7005310058593800"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 17,
      "custom_attributes": [
        {
          "attribute_code": "score",
          "value": "10.6687831878662110"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "aggregations": {
    "buckets": [
      {
        "name": "category_bucket",
        "values": [
          {
            "value": "17",
            "metrics": [
              "17",
              "1"
            ]
          },
          {
            "value": "1497",
            "metrics": [
              "1497",
              "1"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "bucket_names": [
      "category_bucket"
    ]
  },
  "search_criteria": {
    "request_name": "quick_search_container",
    "filter_groups": [
      {
        "filters": [
          {
            "field": "search_term",
            "value": "simple",
            "condition_type": "eq"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "total_count": 2
}
```

So, we found 2 products with ids: 1497, 17.

Also aggregations shown layered navigation by in category 17: 1 product and in 1497: 1 product